# TensorFlow on Windows: "pip install tensorflow" fails

Tags: visual-studio-2015, pip, tensorflow, windows-10, python-3.5

I am using Visual Studio 2015, Python 3.5.2, Windows 10, and have recently upgraded pip to 9.0.1. I am trying to install Tensorflow 0.12 on my system. I tried to use VS's built in "Install Python Package" function, as well as command prompting

```
pip install python
```

Both ways I get the same error:

```
Installing 'tensorflow'
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
'tensorflow' failed to install. Exit code: 1`
```

I don't know what to do from here. Supposedly the pip command was all I had to do so nowhere else has any troubleshooting.

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2013, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the text that is printed out when you run Python? (e.g. `Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32` is what it prints on my workstation.)

Comment: Done, it's up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your Python version string, you are running the 32-bit version of the Python interpreter. We have only made PIP packages for the **64-bit** version of the Python 3.5, which can be downloaded and installed separately from Python.org or Anaconda.

Answer (score -1):

Pip does not come with a tensorflow package.  You need to add it. You can follow the tensorflow windows install directions.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation-on-windows

For the cpu.

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

For the gpu.

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: I tried copying these into my command prompt, both my default one and the one at ~\Python\Python35-32, neither of them worked. The error was `tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`